# Regular Expression where a number is less than 10

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have a table with a column where I have data stored this way:

```
1:29,3:20,5:0,4:0,2:76
```

I want to make a query request in PHP (or MySQL in general) and get rows where there is a number less than 10 after the `" : "`.

Therefore, in this case I have `( 29 , 20 , 0 , 0 , 76 )`, and because I have a number less than 10, I will want to take this row.

Comment: Don't store serialized values when you had a need to inspect individual values inside the serialization. Break those out into their own table and query them normally.

Comment: A schema like this is a pretty clear violation of the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). If possible try and restructure this into a one-to-many relational structure as that will make your query almost trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, storing comma separated values is not considered a good design in SQL, as it leads to violation of data normalization rules and in addition faces many other issues. But since you have already done it and want a regex solution to your problem, you can use this regex,

```
:[0-9](,|$)
```

[Here is a demo](https://regex101.com/r/b73EU2/1)

In mysql you can write a query like this,

```
select * from tablename where columnname regexp ':[0-9](,|$)';
```

This will give you rows where at least one comma separated value is less than ten following a colon.

Comment: I am using a opencart system and this is a module, so I cannot re-design it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: ok, in that case you can't do much. Hope my regex works well for you. Let me know in case you face any issues.

Comment: It is working like charm. But I just realised that I would need a way to sort the result. I mean, when I get the row I'd like to order the products in ASC/DESC depending on this regex ( 5:[0-200](,|$)) - > 5 will be an number that will be chosen from a dropdown menu

Comment: Ordering on value of column is possible but don't think you can order on value of regex. And in your case, since the column stores comma separated values, ordering will further become hard as you might desire.

Comment: Actually I tried to use :[0-200](,|$) but it didn't work for the example you game me here [link](https://regex101.com/r/b73EU2/2)

Comment: If anyone has the same need, here is the solution:
`:(?:200|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])(,|$)`

Comment: `(?:` is not supported before MySQL 8.0.